# Extract the line where some number [range 1-6] followed by a character at the beginning or end of the number in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a txt file with lots of line including number and string.I need to Print the whole line where I find some number with or without followed by a character in the beginning or end of the number.I want to search with the ETEXT NO in my file show the corresponding title and author and also the ETEXT NO.
I tried some pattern["^[a-zA-Z]\d{1,6}$[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVxYp.png)"] but not working.

Comment: Instead of an image, could you add some text examples with the expected matches?

Comment: My match should return the whole line including the Etext number,the author and the book name...like [Aspects of plant life; with special reference to the British flora,      56900
 by Robert Lloyd Praeger]

Comment: Do you want to view the line including the string(`numbers+char`) of ETEXT NO which must be a searching key ?

Comment: yes.I want to the print the whole line including the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
ss="""qtrueofahkdls fhdksafkhkdsa       54355j   by reuwoqryoew rewo
fdshkagkdsu,fdkls fdshl, jfdkls   u65432   by fjdls fjdlks
dslfakdsafkd fdjsklafd,fjdskl      543322  by fjdlsfdsl fdsjkl
dslfakdsafkd fdjsklafd,fjdskl      54333  by fjdlsfdsl fdsjkl
dslfakdsafkd fdjsklafd,fjdskl      u5433  by fjdlsfdsl fdsjkl"""

num=""
while re.match("^[a-z]?\d{1,6}[a-z]?$", num)== None: num= input("please input ETEXT number : ")
regx=re.compile(r'(?im)^.*?\b{}\b.*$'.format(num))
for m in regx.findall(ss): print(m)
```

in which `receives input` ETEXT number (`numbers + (prefix or suffix)character`) and `finds` lines including that ETEXT number and `displays` matching lines.

Input limit `regex` (for ETEXT NUM format),

```
^[a-z]?\d{1,6}[a-z]?$
```

and `finding regex` for input string, `num`

```
r'(?im)^.*?\b{}\b.*$'.format(num)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but there is a problem with this.If I search for 5433 it returns 3 of them but I don't want to do that.I want the exact matching and if the match is exact then return only that line, not any others.Note to be pointed that the ETEXT number is in ascending order and there is no repetition.

Comment: `Human's memories & inputs are  ambiguous in most cases`, so I determined it for your retrying search oppotunity. If you want only one matched output line, pls retry regex and python code. I edited for your need already.

Comment: Hey, man, I tried for the search function in the last line of your code(replacing findall) but it shows some error.And I'n bit confused about why did you run the while loop in re.match line.Can you please explain it.Thanks